# rendering to the canvas usiing raw UInt16Array values javascript

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas, html5-canvas, uint16

I'm trying to render an image from a Uint16Array in javascript.
I am not getting any caught errors, but nothing is rendering to the canvas.

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const bufferMemoryAllocation = cellCount*2; //double the size 2bytes--16bits--per memory slot
const bitArray = new SharedArrayBuffer(bufferMemoryAllocation); // double the number of cells
const pixelData = new SharedArrayBuffer(bufferMemoryAllocation);
const pixelDataCanvas =  new Uint16Array(pixelData);

const videoResolutions = [{name: "test", height: 1000, width:1000},{name:"1080", height: 1080, width:1920},{name:"4k", height: 2160, width:3840}];
canvas.height = videoResolutions[2].height;
canvas.width =  videoResolutions[2].width;

const cellScale = 2;
const drawHeight = Math.floor(canvas.height/cellScale);

const drawWidth = Math.floor(canvas.width/cellScale);
const cellCount=drawHeight*drawWidth;
```

```
function renderToCanvas()
    {
    ctx.drawImage(renderToImage(pixelDataCanvas),0,0,drawWidth,drawHeight); 
}
function renderToImage(pixelDataReffernce)
    {let imageObject = new Image(canvas.height,canvas.width);
    let imageString = 'data:image/bmp;base64,'+btoa(pixelDataReffernce);
    imageObject.src = imageString;
    // console.log(imageObject);
    return imageObject;
}
```

pixelDataReffernce consoles out to::

```
  Uint16Array(2073600) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1024, 1024, 1024, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1024, 0, 0, 0, 1024, 1024, 1024, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1024, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1024, 0, 1024, 1024, 1024, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1024, 0, 0, 0...
```

EDIT_

it was that I wasn't using a 4 channel color array, but a binary channel for color. the solution was to increase the size of recorded color to 4 bytes long, and view it on the main thread as 1byte long.
however: if i try to access the SharedMemory with
new Uint8ClampedArray(data.buffer), i get the following console warning.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'ImageData': The provided ArrayBufferView value must not be shared.
```

so the next step around was to make temp array on the main thread;

```
    const pixelTransViewer = new Uint8Array(pixelData);
    const tA = new Uint8ClampedArray(data.buffer);
    for(let i=0;i<tA.length;i++)
        {   
        for(let j=0;j < 8;j++)
            {
            tA[i]=setBitState(tA[i],j,checkBit(pixelTransViewer[i],j));
        }
    }
    const img = new ImageData(tA, span);
```

but that's literally just rezipping information from sharedMememory to a new memory slot for every render... effectively drawing the same information to an array twice.
is there a faster way for me to get the pixelData out of sharedMemory and onto the canvas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you have are raw RGBA pixel data, then all you need is to [create an ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/ImageData) from your Uint16Array and [put it on your canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData).

```js
const img_width = 50;
const img_height = 50;
const data = new Uint16Array((img_width * img_height) * 2 );
// make some noise
crypto.getRandomValues(data);

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = img_width;
canvas.height = img_height;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const img = new ImageData(
  new Uint8ClampedArray(data.buffer),
  img_width,
  img_height
);
ctx.putImageData( img, 0, 0 );
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Your code did not produce any error because you were not listening to it. If you add a listener to the `error` event of your `imageObject`, you'll see it failed to load what you fed it with, because an image is not just raw pixel data, it also has headers, at least to tell the size of the image.

Comment: I have tried adding an addevent listener - but neither the canvas registers any error, nor does ctx attach at all, but after reading your comment, I changed the format to capture the 8bit4channel color data, and now it's rendering nicely to the canvas... however - scaling the image  - every solution i ran across defeats the purpose of rendering once to an image. so that's what I'm struggling with now - editing my post above with an update.

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'ImageData': The provided ArrayBufferView value must not be shared." - I need to make a new array and copy it over - is there a way to work with the sharedData directly?

Comment: no, the data must belong to the ImageData. Simply copy it to a normal ArrayBuffer. Why do you want a SharedArrayBuffer btw? And to avoid GC, just store that ImageData and update its ArrayBuffer every frame, no need to reallocate anything new.

Comment: Ps: editing questions after they've been answered in a way that invalidates existing answers is frowned upon in StackOverflow and is considered harsh. Let alone unaccepting it when doing so... We prefer you ask a new question with the new details instead.

Comment: aye, sorry for not explaing why i'm using a shared array.
and you way works, with a bit of love.
i'm running calculations in parallel with webworkers (splitting up the work, so each worker works on a section) - in other words, are you saying there's no way to create an image directly from shared memory?, that you need to assign it to a non-shared memory every time?

Comment: Yes and no ;-) You cannot use SharedMemory indeed, but you don't need to reassign it everytime. You can very well create only once your ImageData, and store it, e.g `imgData = new ImageData( width, height); const arr16  new Uint16Array( imgData.data.buffer );`. This way at each frame all you'd do is `arr16.set( sharredArray ); ctx.putImageData( imgData )`. No new memory is used.